# celery worker crash when i start another

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

i use django with celery and redis.
I would like to have three queues und three workers.

My celery settings in the settings.py looks like this:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

# CELERY QUEUES SETUP
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'
CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('manually_crawl', Exchange('manually_crawl'), routing_key='manually_crawl'),
    Queue('periodically_crawl', Exchange('periodically_crawl'), routing_key='periodically_crawl'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'api.tasks.crawl_manually': {'queue': 'manually_crawl', 'routing_key': 'manually_crawl',},
    'api.tasks.crawl_periodically': {'queue': 'periodically_crawl', 'routing_key': 'periodically_crawl',},
    'api.tasks.crawl_firsttime': {'queue': 'default', 'routing_key': 'default',},
}
```

Later i will start the workers with celery multi, but in the development phase i would like to start the worker manually to see errors or so.

I start the redis server with `redis-server` and than i start the first worker default with:

```
celery -A proj worker -Q default -l debug -n default_worker
```

If i try to start the next worker in a new terminal with:

```
celery -A proj worker -Q manually_crawl -l debug -n manually_crawl
```

I get an error in the first default worker terminal:

```
[2019-10-28 09:32:58,284: INFO/MainProcess] sync with celery@manually_crawl
[2019-10-28 09:32:58,290: ERROR/MainProcess] Control command error: OperationalError("\nCannot route message for exchange 'reply.celery.pidbox': Table empty or key no longer exists.\nProbably the key ('_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox') has been removed from the Redis database.\n")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 439, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 518, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 203, in _publish
    mandatory=mandatory, immediate=immediate,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 605, in basic_publish
    message, exchange, routing_key, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/exchange.py", line 70, in deliver
    for queue in _lookup(exchange, routing_key):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 877, in _lookup
    exchange, redis_key))
kombu.exceptions.InconsistencyError:
Cannot route message for exchange 'reply.celery.pidbox': Table empty or key no longer exists.
Probably the key ('_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox') has been removed from the Redis database.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/pidbox.py", line 46, in on_message
    self.node.handle_message(body, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 145, in handle_message
    return self.dispatch(**body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 115, in dispatch
    ticket=ticket)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 151, in reply
    serializer=self.mailbox.serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 285, in _publish_reply
    **opts
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 181, in publish
    exchange_name, declare,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 551, in _ensured
    errback and errback(exc, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 444, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/vine/five.py", line 194, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 439, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 518, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 203, in _publish
    mandatory=mandatory, immediate=immediate,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 605, in basic_publish
    message, exchange, routing_key, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/exchange.py", line 70, in deliver
    for queue in _lookup(exchange, routing_key):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 877, in _lookup
    exchange, redis_key))
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError:
Cannot route message for exchange 'reply.celery.pidbox': Table empty or key no longer exists.
Probably the key ('_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox') has been removed from the Redis database.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem currently with the kombu library, according to this post by downgrading to 4.6.4 and for some people 4.6.3 it solves the problem

```
jorijinnall commented 11 days ago
Had the same issue.
I fixed by downgrading kombu from 4.6.5 to 4.6.3
I still had the bug in version 4.6.4
```

[link github](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1063)

Answer (score 0):

You can start multiple workers like shown below:

```
$ celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=4 -n wkr1@hostname
$ celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=2 -n wkr2@hostname
$ celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=2 -n wkr3@hostname
```

In the above example, there are three workers which will be able to spawn 4,2,2 child processes. It is normally advised to run a single worker per machine and the concurrency value will define how many processes will run in parallel.

The default number of those processes is equal to a number of cores on that machine, normally.

I hope this could help you.